# Call exported functions of DLL in assembly without .lib file

Tags: windows, assembly, dll, masm

So I'm currently trying to call the exported functions of a dll inside my assembly file.
The DLL is in the same directory as my asm program, I don't have the `.lib` file.

Here is my code:

```
EXTERN __imp__CreateCompressor@12:PROC
EXTERN __imp__Compress@24:PROC
EXTERN __imp__CloseCompressor@4:PROC

.code
START:
            push 2 ;COMPRESS_ALGORITHM_MSZIP
            push 0
            push  OFFSET hCompress
            call    __imp__CreateCompressor@12

            push 0 ;CompressedDataSize
            push DWORD ptr [DataSize] ;CompressedBufferSize
            push eax ;CompressedBuffer
            push DWORD ptr [DataSize]
            push DWORD ptr [pBuf3]
            push DWORD ptr [hCompress]
            call __imp__Compress@24

            push DWORD ptr [hCompress]
            call __imp__CloseCompressor@4
END START
```

However I get the errors:

```
file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___imp__CreateCompressor@12
file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___imp__Compress@24
file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___imp__CloseCompressor@4
file.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I'm assembling it like so:
`ml file.asm /link /subsystem:console /entry:START`

Any ideas?

Comment: `EXTERN __imp__CreateCompressor@12:DWORD` must be. not `PROC` and so on for *__imp_* symbols

Comment: than you need add *Cabinet.lib* for linker input

Comment: You must have the .lib file to resolve the linker errors.  Not hard to come by, it is included with the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

To enable [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking) the linker needs an import library.

Without an import library you're going to have to use [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-run-time-dynamic-linking).

Alternatively, you can generate an import library yourself. The easiest way to do so is to author an appropriate [Module-Definition (.Def) File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files) and have the [Microsoft Librarian Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/lib-reference) (LIB.exe) generate an import library.

Comment: not think that *.def* will be enough here. we can not set how many parameters have function if use *def* only. so impossible generate say `__imp__Compress@24`. but possible use *def* in conjunction with *c/c++* where we define dummy function "implementation", say `void __stdcall Compress(int,int,int,int,int,int){}` - and this already give `__imp__Compress@24` in *lib*

Comment: @rbm A .def file is sufficient to create an import library. An import library is sufficient to describe where to find a symbol, which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: you mistake - how can linker know, how decorate symbol by def only in *x86* ? if we declare `Compress` - what symbol must be in lib ? `_Compress` ? `_Compress@0` ? `_Compress@4` ? `_Compress@24` ? `_Compress@32` ? `@Compress@8` ?

Comment: @rbm No one was suggesting that the linker needed to guess. A linker just resolves symbols. And with the .def file holding the decorated symbol names, there's no second-guessing involved when using an import library generated from that .def file.

Comment: ok, we put `Compress@24` to the *def* file. linker put `_Compress@24` and `__imp__Compress@24` to the lib, but `_Compress@24` as import name in resulting PE. but we need `Compress` (because *cabinet.dll* export such `Compress` without decorations)

Comment: try do this by self :) for any name which you put to *def* file - linker (with */MACHINE:x86* option) add `_` prefix. and this will be in import. but this is wrong name. so single def ok only for *__cdecl* calling convention

Comment: @rbm A .def file allows you to rename symbols.

Comment: which symbol name will be in exe import table ? we need exactly `Compress` without decoration (because in exactly this form symbol exported). i can only advice you - try by self create *lib* only from *def* which will be useful

Comment: @rbm That' not what the question is asking for. If you want to answer a different question, go ahead and create a new Q&A,

Comment: @rbm A .def file can *clearly* name the imports the question is looking to import. If you want to answer a different question, create a Q&A that's all yours.

Comment: simply try by self - and look for result

Comment: again - you mistake - if symbol not begin with `?` (*c++* name) and `@` (*__fastcall*) - linker append `_` prefix to the name. and put such name (begin with `_`) in import table !! but this is wrong result. we need name without `_` in **import table**.  try by self create *def* file (without c/c++) which correct import **__stdcall** name

Comment: @rbm How does any of this apply here? All of the symbols the question is asking to import start with an underscore. Where is the issue that you keep trying to solve?

Comment: *cabinet.dll* export *Compress* symbol. so we need import *Compress* symbol. and what must be in *def* file for linker create *Compress* import name ? absolute concrete question. you can answer ? `Compress` ? but linker put `_Compress` in import in this case. `Compress@24` ? but `_Compress@24` will be in import ? so what we need write in *def* for got `Compress` in import ?

Comment: *Call exported functions of DLL in assembly* - and how ? if with lib will be generated **wrong** name in import ? only not say that you not understand what i write.

Comment: possible as solution (for use from asm only) declare names in def as `Compress`, `CreateCompressor`, etc.. in this case in import will be correct names. and use it from *asm* as `__imp__Compress:DWORD`, `__imp__CreateCompressor`, etc.. will be correct work. but such lib will be wrong if wry use it from *c/c++* - if function actual *__stdcall* - *c/c++* will be try use `__imp__CreateCompressor@12`, ..

Answer (score 0):

You must use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` functions to load the library and get the address from the function you want to call.

Comment: can, but not must. better link with *Cabinet.lib*

Comment: @RbMm, The OP said he doesn't have a `lib` file, so he must load the `dll` dynamically.

Comment: this lib is part of microsoft SDK . so all what need - simply download it

Comment: @RbMm, in that case, this would indeed be a solution. :)

Comment: lib-files aren't especially magical anyway, you can take a list of function names and use the `lib` utility to make a lib-file out of them .. and OP doesn't even need to do it, because this lib-file already exists

Comment: I'm aware of four methods how to import a function from DLL, see https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/#EaFnLinkDynamic